# rosdep doesn't recognize OS

Tags: rosdep, ros-fuerte, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to install ROS fuerte on my raspberry pi running raspian (debian based). Everything is running fairly smooth, however rosdep doesn't seem to recognize my OS, even though I've set it using ROS_OS_OVERRIDE.

Executing: `python -m rospkg.os_detect`
results in:

```
OS Name:     debian
OS Version:  squeeze
OS Codename:
```

But executing: `rosdep install -a`
results in:

```
Executing script below with cwd=/tmp
{{{
#!/bin/bash
export PREFIX=/usr/
[ f932cebad87302d8ea0ec1fd39b24d99 = `cat $PREFIX/include/eigen3/eigen-version.installed` ]

}}}

cat: /usr//include/eigen3/eigen-version.installed: No such file or directory
/tmp/tmpeXADPG: line 3: [: f932cebad87302d8ea0ec1fd39b24d99: unary operator expected
Executing script below with cwd=/tmp
{{{
#!/bin/bash
export PREFIX=/usr/
if [ -f $PREFIX/include/assimp/assimp-version.installed ]; then
  [ 2ed0b9954bcb2572c0dade8f849b9260 = `cat $PREFIX/include/assimp/assimp-version.installed` ]
else
  false
fi

}}}

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rosconsole: No definition of [log4cxx] for OS version []
srdf: No definition of [log4cxx] for OS version []
nodelet_topic_tools: No definition of [log4cxx] for OS version []
collada_urdf: No definition of [log4cxx] for OS version []
filters: No definition of [log4cxx] for OS version []
test_bond: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
diagnostic_aggregator: No definition of [log4cxx] for OS version []
roslib: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
eigen_conversions: No definition of [log4cxx] for OS version []
tf: No definition of [log4cxx] for OS version []
nodelet: No definition of [log4cxx] for OS version []
simmechanics_to_urdf: No definition of [log4cxx] for OS version []
timestamp_tools: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
test_nodelet: No definition of [log4cxx] for OS version []
robot_state_publisher: No definition of [log4cxx] for OS version []
resource_retriever: No definition of [log4cxx] for OS version []
test_diagnostic_aggregator: No definition of [log4cxx] for OS version []
tf_conversions: No definition of [log4cxx] for OS version []
bondcpp: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
pluginlib: No definition of [log4cxx] for OS version []
bondpy: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
bond: No definition of [boost] for OS version []
```

Since the version brackets are empty, I'm guessing that rosdep doesn't acurately recognizes the OS Override. Is there another flag I can set?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40081/rosdep-doesn%27t-recognize-os/) by [NsN](https://answers.ros.org/users/1786/nsn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2012-07-28

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS_OS_OVERRIDE does not (seem to) affect rosdep install.  I don't know if this is by design or an oversight. However, I got it to work by manually setting the [os override option](http://ros.org/doc/api/rosdep2/html/commands.html#options) on the command line when calling rosdep:

```
rosdep resolve <key-name> --os=OS_NAME:OS_VERSION
```

This option will work with the other rosdep commands such as rosdep install. I did this (to trick rosdep for my Linaro/Ubuntu system):

```
rosdep install -ay --os=ubuntu:oneiric
```

---

Originally posted by [rlinsalata](https://answers.ros.org/users/2578/rlinsalata/) with karma: 271 on 2012-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-08-26**:
Related ticket: https://github.com/ros/rosdep/issues/10

**Comment by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on 2013-07-20**:
what is  in this post. please explain. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A workaround for this issue (until/if you get it fixed) is to not use rosdep, as all it does is install dependencies for you.  Just install them yourself.

I am using an openSUSE system and rosdep will not work for me because the get_codename python function is not available on whatever revision number I have (along with a number of other issues, of which I started to try to fix).  I just skipped using rosdep and I had no other issues.

---

Originally posted by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) with karma: 506 on 2012-07-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NsN](https://answers.ros.org/users/1786/nsn/) on 2012-07-30**:
So, should I just install the current versions of boost, log4cxx, etc? Does ROS look for specific versions or will it try to use whatever is installed?

**Comment by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) on 2012-07-30**:
Not sure of the answer to that, but I'm using boost version 1.46.1 and ROS Fuerte works fine for me.  I believe I had a problem with boost version 1.49 using ROS Electric, but I cant say that for certain.  I would try the packages your debian package manager comes with first (the default ones).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On openSUSE /etc/SuSE-brand file is missing. A workaround is to create a SUSE-brand file in /etc/ with the following text in it:

```
openSUSE
VERSION = <your openSUSE version, e.g 13.1>
```

---

Originally posted by [usiraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/20174/usiraj/) with karma: 11 on 2014-09-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem using elemntary OS luna.

You should add an environment variable named "ROS_OS_OVERRIDE" which it's value must be your distribution info.
eOs luna is based on ubuntu 12.04 and I'm using Bash Shell. Setting environment variables may be different in other command shells.

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID="elementary OS"
DISTRIB_RELEASE=0.2
DISTRIB_CODENAME=luna
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="elementary OS Luna"
```

You need the first three lines.

```
$ export ROS_OS_OVERRIDE="DISTRIB_ID:DISTRIB_RELEASE:DISTRIB_CODENAME"
```

Which in my case it will be:

```
$ export ROS_OS_OVERRIDE="elementary OS:0.2:luna"
```

Log out your system then log in again. Now if you check your `os.environ` in python, the ROS_OS_OVERRIDE will be exist.

```
>>> import os
>>> "ROS_OS_OVERRIDE" in os.environ
True
>>> os.environ["ROS_OS_OVERRIDE"]
'elementary OS:0.2:luna'
```

Now you can run `rosdep update` successfully.

---

Originally posted by [h3disam](https://answers.ros.org/users/21937/h3disam/) with karma: 21 on 2015-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2